# SQL Truncate then Bulk Insert- Exceeding Max Row Size- Why?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, truncate

I have an export (with a comma in a couple number fields that I needed to delete) that I've been exporting to my SQL Server in a table for the past few days. All I do is `Truncate` the table and replace with whatever is in the export. Just today, I got this error:

`Warning: The table "myTable" has been created, but its maximum row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes. INSERT or UPDATE to this table will fail if the resulting row exceeds the size limit.`

The only thing I can think of happening is that every time I `Bulk Insert` into the table, it somehow takes up some space in the table that I'm not aware of. The export only has about 150 rows of data so I really just have no idea what's going on. Does anyone know?

Here is my code:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [myTable]


ALTER TABLE [myTable]
ALTER COLUMN [Numbercolumn1] NVARCHAR(50)

ALTER TABLE [myTable]
ALTER COLUMN [Numbercolumn2] NVARCHAR(50)


BULK INSERT [SALES server].DBO.[myTable]
FROM 'C:\exports\myTable_EXPORT.TXT'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0X0A'
)

UPDATE [myTable]
SET [Numbercolumn1] = REPLACE([Numbercolumn1],',',''),
[Numbercolumn2] = REPLACE([Numbercolumn2],',','')


ALTER TABLE [myTable]
ALTER COLUMN [Numbercolumn1] FLOAT

ALTER TABLE [myTable]
ALTER COLUMN [Numbercolumn2] FLOAT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max rowsize is referring to the width of the row, not the number of rows.  Each row is only allowed to be so many bytes - 8060 -  wide.  If you have defined a row, with all of it's fields to be greater than 8060, the row cannot be created.  This is a warning instead of an error because of datatypes like VARCHAR that are variable width.  Assuming every single byte in the variable width field is not allocated to a value, you will probably be OK.

Comment: Hmm... I dropped the table and recreated it instead of truncating and I didn't run into the error. I also created a test table for the export and laid on the F5 button until I came up with the error and it seemed to take about 2 solid minutes until it did. Could this be something wrong with the export? Maybe it's not delimiting correctly sometimes?

Comment: Try running this on your table and see what you get   SELECT sum(sc.length) as rowWidth
 FROM sys.syscolumns sc
  join sys.tables st on st.object_id = sc.id
   and st.object_id =object_id('yourTableNameHERE')

Comment: That's good.  That confirms the warning is coming from the source in addition to my original answer.  For whatever reason, the Bulk Insert operation is defining a row width greater than the  max allowed, assuming every byte is used on the row.  It is possible the parsing is not working correctly and its somehow combining several rows into one.